# How to do authentication and redirects in ReactJs with just hooks or states?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, redirect, forms-authentication

Are there any particular way to make authentication and redirects in ReactJs without using Auth0/JWT or others alike? Also saving the data in local storage.

Building a simple react app, and I don't want to make use of any authentication methods and wanted to know how I could achieve this with just hooks/states in ReactJs

Answer (score 0):

You use either cookie sessions or a jwt. These are both used for communication with backend servers and each has its disadvantages and advantages.

You would use a form input and useState such as:

```
const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");

...


<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" 
onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
```

Then you would have a function for onClick or onSubmit that would send this data to the backend server(using Axios or fetch). As you said you want to store it on the local storage, which you should not store passwords like that, then you would do
`localStorage.setItem("email", email);`